# Como usar XML dentro de uma variável String

Tags: java, string, xml

Criei uma variável do tipo **String** que possui o retorno do webservice em XML:

Exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<books>
    <book>
        <author>
            <firstName>Bert</firstName>
            <id>1</id>
            <lastName>Bates</lastName>
        </author>
        <isbn>ISBN-45565-45</isbn>
        <title>Head First Java</title>
    </book>
</books>
```

Se eu quiser pegar o valor "ISBN-45565-45" está dentro da tag , como proceder??? Estou usando java.

Answer (score 1):

Poderia pesquisar dentro da string, mas não é a melhor forma, se a string é um documento XML válido, melhor converter para um XML Document e pesquisar o valor dentro da tag usando `getElementsByTagName`.

Assim por exemplo:

```
String xmlStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>" +
                        "<books>" +
                        "   <book>" +
                        "       <author>" +
                        "           <firstName>Bert</firstName>" +
                        "           <id>1</id>" +
                        "           <lastName>Bates</lastName>" +
                        "       </author>" +
                        "       <isbn>ISBN-45565-45</isbn>" +
                        "       <title>Head First Java</title>" +
                        "   </book>" +
                        "</books>";


        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
        DocumentBuilder builder;  
        try  
        {  
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
            Document doc = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlStr ) ) ); 

            var node = doc
                .getElementsByTagName("isbn")
                .item(0)
                .getTextContent();
                
            System.out.println(node); 
                
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            System.out.println(e);  
        }
```

Pode ver funcionando aqui: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/7oNNmFZ

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo a pergunta, há algumas formas, uma que considero sensata e robusta seria procurar uma boa biblioteca para fazer *parsing* do XML para Java, possivelmente alguma que já esteja disponível na biblioteca-padrão da linguagem, e aprender a usá-la para parsear o seu XML. Sugiro como palavras-chaves para isso no buscador da sua preferência `XML` `parser` `Java` `library`. Não vou dar sugestões porque essa informação vai mudando e deixaria a resposta desatualizada.

Embora algumas certamente forneçam funcionalidades de percorrer automaticamente o XML em busca do que quer, a mais provável forma de usar será você, mediante conhecimento prévio das partes que compõem a árvore XML (só encontrei essa informação em inglês, por exemplo [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp)) e do formato dos dados XML que vêm no web service, especificar via programação ao usar a biblioteca por quais partes precisa navegar no XML até encontrar a informação desejada (por exemplo, no seu caso teria que especificar para entrar no elemento-raiz `books`, lá dentro navegar por cada (obs.: cacófato) um dos elementos `book` e de cada um extrair o texto do elemento `isbn` contido nele). Tenha em mente também que, por se tratar de uma estrutura de dados do tipo árvore, poderão ser usados na biblioteca termos típicos dessa estrutura como *node* ou nó.

Para conjuntos de dados pequenos como os retornos convencionais de um web service não há problema se a biblioteca realizar todo o carregamento e processamento diretamente na memória, já no caso de XML's maiores pode ser interessante buscar uma mais robusta, que faça um carregamento e processamento graduais. Isso seria mais para arquivos.

Outras formas que no geral são menos robustas de fazer, mas podem servir se você tem certeza do padrão de dado que sempre virá, seria buscar e extrair a informação que quer utilizando expressões regulares ou buscar dentro da string por substrings. Mas como falei são maneiras mais engessadas e menos manuteníveis no caso geral.